# How to redirect if the url have index.php/somefileOrsomedirectory

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

What do i want to do is if the url have `www.example.com/index.php/anything` then it should throw the user to    `www.example.com/error-404`
Here is my current expressions in my htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
Redirect 301 /online-features/key-anywhere-web-based-system http://www.example.com/online-features
Redirect 301 /home http://www.example.com/
```

Thanks in advance.
Please suggest/edit my question if i have not asked the question in correct way.

**EDIT**
I don't want to loose the `/index.php` to `/` redirection.

Comment: I just want to clarify - so if there is any directory and or file, you want it redirected to the 404 error page?

Comment: @thickguru Given the URL `/index.php/anything` - "anything" is additional _path information_, it doesn't relate to a directory or a file.

Comment: @DocRoot
If it is something like 
1) /index.php/string
2) /index.php/directory
3) /index.php/pathwhichdoesnotexists
Then it should redirect to /error-404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `www.example.com/index.php/anything`

`/anything` here is additional *path information* (after the name of a physical file). You can use the `AcceptPathInfo` directive to specifically disable this "feature":

```
AcceptPathInfo Off
```

In which case all URLs containing additional path info will automatically trigger a 404. However, the URLs can still be routed using mod_rewrite, which is probably what's happening here.

You will still need to implement a mod_rewrite redirect as mentioned in the datascript's answer. Or try something like the following, before your existing directives:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.php/ /error-404 [R=302,L]
```

The check against `REDIRECT_STATUS` is to avoid a rewrite loop, since your *front controller* appears to use path info to route the request.

Change this to a `301` if this is intended to be permanent, once you have confirmed it's working OK.

However, it would be preferable if this was implemented as a proper Apache error document. For example:

```
ErrorDocument /error-404.php

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.php/ - [R=404,L]
```

Comment: **/index.php/anything** means it can be a directory or file.

Comment: I have tried this one also, and it's not helping me out.
Please look at my current redirection rules, and then suggest, will a great help for me.
It's working well if i am removing my all redirection, but i dont want to loose these re-directions also.

Comment: And you've included this "before your existing directives"? Something like this will need to go at the top of your file. You also should not mix `Redirect` (mod_alias) and `RewriteRule` (mod_rewrite) directives. Convert the `Redirect` to `RewriteRule`.

Comment: can you write all the rules, once in the answer by editing my code.
I mean 100 % of the code, as it's just the part of the answer.
thanks

Comment: Wait bro, I think it's working.
Let me see for some more time

Answer (score 2):

I think the following should do what you require. The dot is any character and the + means one or more times. 
This would require the forward slash to be there

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.+)$ error-404 [L]
```

EDIT: Thanks @DocRoot, updated accordingly

Comment: Ideally you should escape the first dot in the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ to match a literal dot.

Comment: This: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA] will rewrite everything to index.php that is not a file or directory. Have you tried putting the line in the answer above straight after RewriteBase /   ?